# Integral of FractionalPart function

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form, euler-mascheroni-constant

My learning curve began with a problem on Brilliant:

$\large \int_0^1\int_0^1\lbrace{\frac{x^3}{y}\rbrace}dxdy=\frac{A}{B}-\frac{\gamma}{C}$

I recognized the problem with the lower bound on y being zero. Since for both x and y we are going from 0 to 1, the confusion between the Mathematica/GeoGebra definition for {x} , ie frac(x) and the Graham et al. definition, was not an issue on this question. Then I went ahead and worked out the inside integral to be $\frac{1}{4y}$. With trepidation, and not sure even that step was correct, I was looking at:

$\int_0^1\frac{1}{4y}dy$

That's where I started to spin my wheels, get frustrated and confused. More research followed. More frustration ensued. I then tried to go back and attempt numerical analysis from square one with a double integral tool on GeoGebra.org ..... The best I did there was finding a lower bound of 10 and an upper bound of 20 for the final answer but I am not confident even that's true. I would be happy if all I got was a numerical result accurate to 8 decimal digits but I just can't handle the discontinuity at y=0 I guess. That the Euler-Mascheroni constant .57721566 is involved in the closed form template for the result is very intriguing to me. Currently, the Brilliant site has no posted solutions yet, or I would have put in 3 guesses and got to see it days ago. The tutorial Wikis on Brilliant helped me understand how non-trivial the fractionalPart function is! Sorry about the long story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

> - $0\le x^3 <y \le 1 \implies
>    \left \{ \dfrac{x^3}{y} \right \}=\dfrac{x^3}{y}$

\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x^3}^{1} \left \{ \frac{x^3}{y} \right \} \, dy \, dx
  &= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x^3}^{1} \frac{x^3}{y} \, dy \, dx \\
  &= \frac{3}{16}
\end{align*}

> - $0\le \dfrac{x^3}{n+1} <y \le \dfrac{x^3}{n} \le \dfrac{1}{n} \implies
>      \left \{ \dfrac{x^3}{y} \right \}=\dfrac{x^3}{y}-n$

\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{1} \int_{\frac{x^3}{n+1}}^{\frac{x^3}{n}}
  \left \{ \frac{x^3}{y} \right \} \, dy \, dx
  &= \int_{0}^{1} \int_{\frac{x^3}{n+1}}^{\frac{x^3}{n}}
  \left( \frac{x^3}{y}-n \right) dy \, dx \\
  &= \frac{1}{4} \left( \ln \frac{n+1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: I understand and confirm the first bullet point up to $\frac{3}{16}$ but then I get lost on the second hint. I do know that $\sum_1^\infty\left({ln}\frac{n+1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$ is  $1-\gamma$ . I'm close now.

Comment: Got it !  A=7 ; B=16 ; C=4  Thanks for the help and making me learn some more.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[#ffe,15px]{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\braces{x^{3} \over y}\,\dd x\,\dd y}} =
\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}\int_{0}^{1/x^{3}}\braces{1 \over y}\,\dd y\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}\int_{x^{3}}^{\infty}{\braces{y} \over y^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\braces{y} \over y^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}
\bracks{x < y^{1/3}}\,\dd x\,\dd y =
\int_{0}^{1}{\braces{y} \over y^{2}}\int_{0}^{y^{1/3}}x^{3}\,\dd x\,\dd y +
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\braces{y} \over y^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{3}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}{y \over y^{2/3}}\,\dd y +
{1 \over 4}\int_{1}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over y} - {\left\lfloor y\right\rfloor \over y^{2}}}\,\dd y =
{3 \over 16} +
{1 \over 4}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\int_{n}^{n + 1}\pars{{1 \over y} - {n \over y^{2}}}\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
{3 \over 16} +
{1 \over 4}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{\ln\pars{1 + n} - \ln\pars{n} + {n \over n + 1} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
{3 \over 16} +
{1 \over 4}\lim_{N \to \infty}\bracks{\sum_{n = 1}^{N}
\ln\pars{1 + n} - \sum_{n = 1}^{N}\ln\pars{n} - \sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{3 \over 16} +
{1 \over 4}\lim_{N \to \infty}\bracks{\sum_{n = 2}^{N + 1}
\ln\pars{n} - \sum_{n = 1}^{N}\ln\pars{n} - \sum_{n = 2}^{N + 1}{1 \over n}} =
{3 \over 16} +
{1 \over 4}\lim_{N \to \infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{N + 1} + 1 -
\sum_{n = 1}^{N + 1}{1 \over n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\ds{{7 \over 16} - {1 \over 4}\,\gamma}}
\end{align}